# wordpress : facebook comment

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i hope you don't mind if i ask this question here, however,

is there any wordpress plugin that allow us to comment using facebook account ?

for example, there's a case like this,

i've made an article about stackoverflow in myblog.com, then i share them to my facebook fanpage of myblog.com. then, a friend of mine comment in the fanpage facebook. when i open the page myblog.com/stackoverflow , i am able to see my friends comment here, and i am able to reply them from the site using facebook account. then, my comment is shown in my facebook fanpage

is there any wordpress plugin to be the solution of my mentioned case ? do i have to modify some facebook comment or facebook API to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wordpress Plugin '[facebook-comments-master](https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-comments-master/)'  . I think this will help to implment the facebook comment in your blog directly. Or you can try onther plugin [facebook-comments-plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook-comments-plugin/)